# EF Core 2.0 OwnsOne column prefix

Tags: ef-core-2.0

When using OwnsOne to map complex types, the sql column name is prefixed with the attribute name. Is it possible to specify the prefix name in the mapping?

This is my mapping:

```
e.OwnsOne(x => x.Attributes, cb =>
{
    cb.OwnsOne(a => a.Supplier);
});
```

I would like the sql column to be prefixed with "Attr_" Instead of "Attributes_". Is this possible?

Comment: Currently this convention is [hardcoded](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/dev/src/EFCore.Relational/Metadata/Internal/ConstraintNamer.cs#L110). You may post a feature request to https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues. The workaround is to configure explicitly column names for all properties (including those of the nested owned type).

Comment: @Ivan Stoev,  Do you know the syntax to map explicity.  Just tried  in a IEntityTypeConfiguration file: builder.Property(x=>x.Address.Postcode).HasColumnName("PostCode").  but it throws an Exception  ArgumentException: The expression 'ea => ea.Address.Postcode' is not a valid property expression. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'.
Parameter name: propertyAccessExpression

Comment: @Jafin It has to be done through the corresponding `OwnsOne` builder action argument. e.g. `.OwnsOne(e => e.Address, cb =>
{
 cb.Property(e => e.Postcode).HasColumnName("Postcode");
});`

Comment: You can also use data annotations to override column names.
e.g. annotating with `[Column("Supplier")]` will use that for column name without prefix.
The attribute `Column` exists in the namespace `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema`
This method has the advantage of being local to the entity class file so other developers adding additional properties can notice the need to override column names by noting existing properties.

Answer (score 5):

You could write an extension method to override the names of all columns;

```cs
   public static void WithPrefix<T, R>(this OwnedNavigationBuilder<T, R> builder, string prefix) where T:class where R:class
   {
      foreach (var p in builder.OwnedEntityType.GetProperties())
         p.SetColumnName($"{prefix}{p.Name}");
   }

   .OwnsOne(e => e.Address, cb => cb.WithPrefix(""));
```

Answer (score 2):

Ivan Stoev's answer from the question comments:

> It has to be done through the corresponding `OwnsOne` builder action argument. e.g. `.OwnsOne(e => e.Address, cb => { cb.Property(e => e.Postcode).HasColumnName("Postcode"); });`

(Making this a community wiki, just marking the question as being answered.)